# How do I add further categories to my left hand menu but NOT to my top menu

Tags: magento, categories

Ive built my first site using a Magento template. I have many categories which I want to show in my left hand menu but DON'T want them to show in the top menu as it will look ugly as will be 3 to 4 rows. Ive searched and searched for a way of doing this which seems quite a simple thing but cannot find an answer?

Ive seen other Magento sites that have this feature so know it must be able to be done!

Please help a newbie : - )

PS I'm new to this forum but it seems somebody has marked my post "down" as unclear? Not sure how I can be any clearer?! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

First click on category then select option `Include in Navigation Menu` to `No` it will not add category to navigation

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick reply. Unfortunately this will also remove it from my left hand menu as well. I just want to hide/remove/delete it from showing on the top menu ONLY.

Comment: which code you write to get category on left menu ?

Comment: Hi, I purchased a template so was all done for me. The site is ladders4you.com if that helps. Thanks again : - )